# MATLAB avoid matrix wrapping in command window

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there a way to prevent MATLAB from wrapping matrices into multiple chunks when displaying them in the command window? Here's what I mean:

```
>> x = rand(10,1);
>> y = rand(10,1);
>> c = squareform(pdist([x y]))

c =

  Columns 1 through 6

         0    0.9160    0.4707    0.7161    0.6093    0.1555
    0.9160         0    0.8495    0.8984    0.6463    1.0714
    0.4707    0.8495         0    0.2459    0.2477    0.5541
    0.7161    0.8984    0.2459         0    0.2603    0.7970
    0.6093    0.6463    0.2477    0.2603         0    0.7306
    0.1555    1.0714    0.5541    0.7970    0.7306         0
    0.0881    0.9695    0.4311    0.6762    0.6012    0.1295
    0.4698    0.4566    0.4587    0.6057    0.3612    0.6245
    0.2442    1.1079    0.7006    0.9460    0.8534    0.1629
    0.8282    0.1355    0.7200    0.7629    0.5114    0.9832

  Columns 7 through 10

    0.0881    0.4698    0.2442    0.8282
    0.9695    0.4566    1.1079    0.1355
    0.4311    0.4587    0.7006    0.7200
    0.6762    0.6057    0.9460    0.7629
    0.6012    0.3612    0.8534    0.5114
    0.1295    0.6245    0.1629    0.9832
         0    0.5156    0.2700    0.8736
    0.5156         0    0.6857    0.3588
    0.2700    0.6857         0    1.0359
    0.8736    0.3588    1.0359         0
```

I'd like to be able to copy and paste the matrix `c` (into a LaTeX document, say, or a MATLAB script) but this is obviously cumbersome with the current output format, especially for larger matrices.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you can use the [variable explorer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/view-edit-and-copy-variables.html#btzcjxw) to view and interact with the whole matrix.

Comment: Or print the contents of the matrix to a text file.

Comment: Variable explorer might be the way to go. From there I can copy and paste the whole matrix. Text file is another option but I prefer to avoid that extra step. @excaza if you want to write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I don't think there's a way to change the command line output. If you don't need a programmatic solution you can utilize the [variable explorer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/view-edit-and-copy-variables.html#btzcjxw) to interact with your data using a slightly Excel-ish interface.

You can access the variable explorer by double clicking on your variable in the workspace browser, right clicking on your variable and selecting `Open`, selecting your variable and hitting `ctrl+D` (on Windows), or programmatically using [`openvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openvar.html).

If you do need a programmatic solution, you can use one of the many exporting functions ([`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), etc.), one example being the answer that @badjr posted.

Answer (score 5):

You could do `fprintf([repmat('%f\t', 1, size(c, 2)) '\n'], c');`, which gave this output:

```
0.000000    0.818064    1.054641    0.342287    0.668041    0.717356    0.597756    0.804045    0.650459    0.815819    
0.818064    0.000000    0.778921    0.485276    0.322136    1.157594    0.833495    0.363079    0.185730    0.060130    
1.054641    0.778921    0.000000    0.917058    0.529164    0.815812    0.556431    0.421934    0.846744    0.837905    
0.342287    0.485276    0.917058    0.000000    0.422061    0.885196    0.638057    0.565268    0.309989    0.476907    
0.668041    0.322136    0.529164    0.422061    0.000000    0.848242    0.518164    0.143653    0.325248    0.368679    
0.717356    1.157594    0.815812    0.885196    0.848242    0.000000    0.333280    0.894846    1.078174    1.191962    
0.597756    0.833495    0.556431    0.638057    0.518164    0.333280    0.000000    0.562174    0.773488    0.871944    
0.804045    0.363079    0.421934    0.565268    0.143653    0.894846    0.562174    0.000000    0.428803    0.420291    
0.650459    0.185730    0.846744    0.309989    0.325248    1.078174    0.773488    0.428803    0.000000    0.167448    
0.815819    0.060130    0.837905    0.476907    0.368679    1.191962    0.871944    0.420291    0.167448    0.000000
```

But it's probably easier to use the [variable explorer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/view-edit-and-copy-variables.html) as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I like this even better than the variable explorer because you can specify a constant output format for all the values.

Comment: This is nice when the output format needs to be a certain way (e.g., inserting into a LaTeX document). But I like the variable explorer way more, in general, since it's faster and I don't have to remember or think through the syntax to produce this table.